# I am not able to login hp unix server via ansible is below error are same?

Tags: ansible

```
FAILED! => {
  "changed": false,
  "failed": true,
  "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.13.5.4 closed.\r\n",
  "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python:  not found.\r\n",
  "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
  "rc": 0
```

Comment: There is an error message for you "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found."

Comment: i installed ansible in redhat machine from i trying getting some information some HP unix server i am facing error like :- /bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found . my question is now i need to install python deps in all HP unix machine?...

Answer (score 1):

The message is pretty clear: `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python:  not found.`

As specified in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements), Ansible needs to have python installed on the managed nodes.

You can install it with ansible by using the [`raw` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html) in a first task:

```
- name: Install python
  raw: yum install -y python # adapt to use the right package manager and package name
  become: yes
```

You can also install it with adhoc command:

```
ansible myhost --sudo -m raw -a "yum install -y python"
```

Comment: I wonder how do you know `yum` is available and working on OP's "hp unix server"...

Comment: I don't, it's an example and it's said to adapt to the package manager (I don't know what it is on hp unix)

Comment: i installed ansible in redhat machine from i trying getting some information some HP unix server i am facing error like :- /bin/sh: /usr/bin/python:  not found . my question is now i need to install python deps in all HP unix machine .

Comment: Yes: python is required on all managed hosts, not only the ansible host.